# Extending a unitary isomorphism on a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $H$ be a Hilbert sapce and $M$ a dense subspace of $H$. Prove that any unitary isomorphism on $M$ can be uniquely extended to a unitary isomorphism on $H$.

So here's what I tried:

Let $T: M \rightarrow M$ be a unitary isomorphism. For all $z \in H$, there exists a sequence $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ s.t.  $\|x_n-z\| \rightarrow 0$. Since $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ converges and $H$ is complete, $\left\lbrace x_n \right\rbrace$ is Cauchy. As $T$ is unitary, $\left\lbrace Tx_n \right\rbrace$ is Cauchy and hence converges to some limit. Let $Tx = lim_n Tx_n$.

At this point, I'm unsure how to show that $Tx \in H$ and that it's unique.

Comment: not sure they meant $T : M \to M$ but instead $T : M \to H$ ? and since $y_n = Tx_n$ is a Cauchy sequence $\in H$, it is clear that $y_n \to y \in H$. and for proving that $y$ doesn't depend on the sequence $(x_n)$ whenever $x_n \to x$, you can use that the obtained operator $\tilde{T}$ is bounded, hence it is continuous.

Comment: I guess it's pretty obvious then that $y \in H$ if it's correct that $T: M \rightarrow H$ instead in retrospect

Comment: (note that since $M \subset H$, if $T : M \to M$ then also $T : M \to H$ ..)

Comment: Yea just checked my notes again, and we have $T: M \rightarrow M$

Comment: in my opinion, you should start with $P_n : H \to M$ the (orthogonal) projection operator $H \to A_n$ a subspace of $M$ such that $A_n \subset A_{n+1}$, and $A_n \to H$ and $P_n \to Id_H$ when $n \to \infty$. hence $P_n$ is bounded, $x_n = P_n x$, and you can define $\tilde{T}$ as $\lim_{n \to \infty} T P_n$, prove that it is bounded, hence continuous, and finally that it is unitary (i.e. that $\|\tilde{T} x\| = \|x\|$ for any $x \in H$)